# How do I add a horizontal line in Gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot

I have a file with data which I plot with Gnuplot as follows

```
set logscale x
set logscale y
plot 'file.txt' using 1:4
```

How do I add an horizontal line to my log-log plot?

The line should be black and at 300

The file looks like this:

```
   32000.0000       3177600.00       311360.000       357.160004       118.309998    
   35000.0000       3176500.00       310990.000       400.489990       128.089996    
   40000.0000       3174300.00       310310.000       472.319977       143.220001    
   45000.0000       3171800.00       309560.000       543.079956       156.940002    
   50000.0000       3168900.00       308750.000       612.309998       169.349991    
   55000.0000       3165700.00       307870.000       679.669983       180.559998    
   63000.0000       3159800.00       306370.000       782.980042       196.209991    
   71000.0000       3153200.00       304740.000       880.349976       209.389999    
   80000.0000       3144800.00       302800.000       982.489990       221.669998    
   90000.0000       3134400.00       300530.000       1086.69995       232.649994    
   100000.000       3123100.00       298160.000       1181.50000       241.279999    
   110000.000       3110800.00       295720.000       1267.09998       247.949997    
   120000.000       3097800.00       293210.000       1344.20007       253.010010    
   140000.000       3069600.00       288090.000       1474.80005       259.319977    
   160000.000       3039100.00       282880.000       1577.80005       261.860016    
   180000.000       3006700.00       277640.000       1657.40002       261.799988    
   200000.000       2973000.00       272420.000       1717.50000       259.930023    
   220000.000       2938200.00       267250.000       1761.40002       256.790009    
   250000.000       2884700.00       259640.016       1802.59998       250.569992    
   280000.000       2830400.00       252240.000       1821.09998       243.240005    
   320000.000       2757600.00       242720.000       1820.09998       232.659988    
   350000.000       2703200.00       235860.000       1805.60010       224.520004    
   400000.000       2613900.00       224970.000       1764.19995       211.050003    
   450000.000       2527100.00       214740.000       1709.30005       198.070007
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer my self:

```
 plot 'file.txt' using 1:4,300
```